# Express JS : How to manage routing by headers request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have Managed an API service base on Express JS. I have 2 or 3 clients that request my API. All the requests from the client are handled by **single monolythic Apps**. Currently, I handle that request with this code:

```js
const express = require('express');
const webRoute = require('./src/routes/web/index')
const cmsRoute = require('./src/routes/cms/index');

app.use('/web', webRoute)
app.use('/cms', cmsRoute)


// This Code works just fine. The routes are defined by URL request
```

But I want the route request not from `Url`, but requested by its Headers.
It looks like this `appKey = 'for-key' appName='web'`

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:3000/cms \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer asfsfafgdgfdgddafaggafafasgfghhjhkgflkjkxjvkjzvxzvz' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: c36d6d5a-14b7-40bf-85e0-1bf255c815de' \
  -H 'appKey: keyloggers' \
  -H 'appName: web (i want by this header)' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Thx for all.

**edit notes:**

In my current code, to call an API I am using this:

`https://localhost:3000/cms/user/profile or https://localhost:3000/web/user/profile`
I want all requests to only use `https://localhost:3000/user/profile` without adding a prefix **web** or **cms**

Comment: In your curl example, you show `appName: web` and `appKey: keyLoggers`.  Are you saying that you want to route using Express so that it works exactly like a request to `/web/keyLoggers`?  And, do you only have this one `appKey` value for that `appName` or do you have lots of `appKey` values that are all in that same router?  Asked another way, how many different `appKey` values are there for a given `appName`?  And, are these all currently specified with `router.get()` handlers in your two routers?

Comment: @jfriend00 , i just have 2 additional headers 
appKey for authenticate and appName for identified user agent client, later on, i will use appName as for routing identify... 
`appName = web` only have access to webAPI and the other for acces to cmsAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment, it appears you want to use a single URL form such as:

```
https://localhost:3000/user/profile
```

And, have it routed to the correct router based on the `appName` custom header.

You can do that by just checking the custom header value and manually sending the request to the desired router.

```
const webRoute = require('./src/routes/web/index')
const cmsRoute = require('./src/routes/cms/index');

// custom middleware to select the desired router based on custom header
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const appName = req.get("appName");
    if (appName === "web") {
        webRoute(req, res, next);
    } else if (appName === "cms") {
        cmsRoute(req, res, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: finally, thx brothers,,,, . so i should passing the `(req, res, next)` params . have a nice day brow

Comment: @shevanto - Yes, the router is itself a middleware function.  So, if calling it manually, you pass it `(req, res, next)` from the current request.  If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.  That will also earn you some reputation  points for following the proper procedure here.

Comment: @shevanto - Keep in mind that cookies from your two separate "apps" will be intermingled (since it's the same host and the same path) so if they are each supposed to have separate auth, for example and were using a cookie to keep track of auth state, they'd each have to use differently named cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default route, then based on request headers, you can redirect to your route.

```js
//consider this a default route. You can arrange any in your program

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  // switch on request header variable value
  
  switch (req.get("appName")) {
  case "web":
    res.redirect('/web')
    break;
  case "cms":
    res.redirect('/cms')
    break;
}
})
```

Comment: in my current code, to call an api using this
`https://localhost:3000/cms/user/profile or https://localhost:3000/web/user/profile`
i want All request only use `https://localhost:3000/user/profile` without add a prefix **web** or **cms**